# How to send variable from Template to Path and use it in a related view function?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-urls

Basically, I have list of persons and i want to implement a details feature for each person so that whenever i click on view besides the particular person row in the table it should send the person's id to the path in the urls.py which then will call the respective view function. I ve tried something and adding the code below but its not working. thanks for reading.

**template.html**

```
                        <tbody>
                        {% for del in delegates %}
                        <tr>
                            <td>{{ del.id }}</td>
                            <td>{{ del.first_name }} {{ del.last_name }}</td>
                            <td>{{ del.email }}</td>
                            <td>{{ del.phone }}</td>
                            <td>{{ del.company }}</td>
                            <td>{{ del.designation }}</td>
                            <td>{{ del.address }}</td>
                            <td>{{ del.city }} ({{ del.pincode }})</td>
//MY VIEW DETAIL BUTTON     <td><a href="{% url 'delegate_details' del_id=del.dataset_id %}">View</a></td>
                        </tr>
                        {% endfor %}
                        </tbody>
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.urls import path
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index),
    path('view-delegates', views.view_delegates),
    path('delegate-details', views.delegate_det),
    url(r'^delegate/(?P<del_id>[0-9]+)$', views.delegate_det, name='delegate_details'),
]
```

**views.py**

```
def delegate_det(request, dataset_id):
    # data = Delegate.objects.all()
    data = Delegate.objects.filter(dataset_id=dataset_id)
    return render(request, 'delegate_details.html', {'delegate': data})
```

P.S: I am a beginner in Python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to correct your views urls and template as follows.

```
def delegate_det(request, dataset_id):
    data = get_object_or_404(Delegate, dataset_id=dataset_id)
    return render(request, 'delegate_details.html', {'delegate': data})
```

url

```
path('delegate/<int:dataset_id>', views.delegate_det, name='delegate'),
```

in your list template

```
<td><a href="{% url 'delegate' dataset_id=del.dataset_id %}">View</a></td>
```